# Spring batch FlatFileWriter concurrency issue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

We have a spring batch application that reads using `JpaPagingItemReader`. The customised Writer extends FlatFileWriter to create record files.

Perhaps relevant code in the class is as follows:

```
public synchronized void write(List<? extends T> list) throws Exception {
    super.write(list);
    // irrelevant line...
}
```

This looks thread safe to me. Do you think there is any problem in terms of multithreading with this piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

That looks good to make the writer thread safe (after creation). FTR, there is an open JIRA ticket [BATCH-2762](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2762) to request this feature.

Comment: That sounds great that there is no issue with the Writer code. I'll check if the implementation of JpaPagingItemReader or the Processor. How feasible is replicating threading issues in a unit test? From what I know the behaviour is random.